# query and paginate multiple post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I'm looking to query multiple post types and paginate them so the results are across multiple pages. The markup I have is as follows:

```
<?php query_posts( array(
     'posts_per_page' => 100,
     'post_type' => array( 'regularproducts', 'wpsc-product' ),
     'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 ),
));
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post_type">
    <?php if ( 'regularproducts' == get_post_type()  ) : ?>FEATURE<?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( 'wpsc-product' == get_post_type()  ) : ?>REPORT<?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> "><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <div class="excerpt">
    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<nav id="page_nav">
    <?php posts_nav_link(' ',' ','load more posts +'); ?>
</nav>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The query works as far as showing both post types, but they're not paginating. i.e. on `/page/2/` it's displaying the same 100 results as page 1, is there a reason for this / solution? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On which page/template are you doing this. Also, never use `query_posts`

Comment: @PieterGoosen It's being used on `page-products.php` template. OK, so is there a way of achieving what I'm after?

Comment: And is this a front page, because if not, `page` must be changed to `paged`

Comment: @PieterGoosen ah yes, changing to `paged` worked a treat! Although for some reason the `wpsc-product` post type aren't being paginated as none of those posts are appearing on page 2 onwards?

Comment: I don't see any reason for this happening from the code given. It is possible that there are no posts to show from that cpt within a specific page or a filter somewhere in your theme that is causing this.